# manipulating a query

Tags: sql, ms-access, row

how can i retrieve the first 10 rows of the firstnames (which is `prepodFamIO` ) found in the prepod table and the sum of the hours in a semester which is greatest the hours are found in plany table(which is `PAuditTime` ,given that the two information are in different tables.

i know if i want to select the first 10 rows of the first names i can run this query

```
select * from prepod 
limit 30;
```

or

```
select * from prepod 
where rownum <= 30;
```

and if i want to select the sum of hours which is greatest

```
SELECT MAX(PAuditTime)
 AS LargestNumber
 FROM plany
 order by PAuditTime;
```

but how can i put them in one query ....i am using sql in access and ms sql thanks
this is a snapshot of my database but im only interested in tables plany and prepod
[image]

Comment: I think we're also going to need your table definitions, and an example of desired results.  Also, barring an `ORDER BY` clause in a statement, the order of results returned in a query is 'undefined' (ignoring vendor-specific details, which should be avoided here).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse the order by clause should order by ptime....its like every name worked certain hours in a semester the relationship of the gtable to pred is one to many the gtable is a foreign key in pred table,i hope i have answered something to make u understand

Comment: Please give use the definitions of your tables (at least a list of columns) or examples of data therein, and the desired output.  Among other things, you haven't yet told us how the two tables are related - this is like asking somebody to generate a list of employees at various companies... and then only handing them census data.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse just edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT TOP 10 prepodFamIO, MAX(PAuditTime)
    FROM Prepod AS pr
    INNER JOIN Plany AS pl ON pr.PlanyId = pl.IDPlany
GROUP BY prepodFamIO
ORDER BY MAX(PAuditTime) DESC
```

...?

Comment: yes it's an alias, you can change it if you want, same for pl